# Как включить проприетарные драйвера InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH:VirtualBox Guest Service в virtualbox с ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

[image: Вот здесь у меня проблема]

я начал использовать virtualbox установил гостевые драйвера, но я не знаю как их включить.Один из способов был обновить пакеты и я их обновил, но ничего не вышло.
ubuntu 20.04LTS а virtual box 6.1

Comment: `aptitude install -y dkms intel-microcode iucode-tool virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11` пробовал?

Comment: Или `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`